# Python 3: Is it possible to close an active listbox using code?

Tags: python-3.x, macos, listbox

I'm learning python (3) and coding a board game as a practice exercise. I want different listboxes to open and close themselves depending on the stage of the game. Thank you for your...input! (heh)

Editing for clarity:

The goal is for the listbox creation function to first check if there are any other open/active listboxes. If there are, to close them.

In effect,I want to guarantee that there is only one listbox open at any given time.

For instance:

```
def stuff_list():

    # creates stuff_list listbox


def another_list():
    # code for 'if any other listbox is open, close it'
    # creates another_list listbox
```

So running this:

```
stuff_list() # opens stuff_list()

another_list() # closes stuff_list and then opens another_list
```

Comment: I am not a python expert, but it seems like you have put very little code and context into this post.  I can’t figure out whether you want to know whether there is a way for a xxx_list() to close any open *_list(), or just have a way to trigger these lists at different points.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I just want to know if I can begin the listbox creation function with a command that closes any open listbox

Comment: are we talking the `tkinter listbox widget`?  And do you need to close it and create a new one or will just clearing it and rewriting to it work?

Comment: yep listbox, or even a text box window as well!

Just clearing it and rewriting could work too, as long as it doesn't require opening another window - i'm trying to avoid a giant cascade of windows forming every time.

Comment: Welcome to the community. If an answer has helped you solve your problem, you should accept it. See [How does accepting an answer work](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a need to destroy your current `listbox` just to create a blank one when you can just erase the one that is there to repopulate it with new info.  I suggest you look into the `listbox` [documentation](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/listbox.htm).
To populate a listbox, you use `listbox.insert()`.  To erase it, you use `listbox.delete()`.  Here's some example code:

```
def populate_listbox():
    listbox.insert(END, "a list entry")
    for item in ["one", "two", "three", "four"]:
        listbox.insert(END, item)

def erase_listbox():
    listbox.delete(0, END)
```